# .net core RC2 using own local Nuget Package: The folder netstandard1.5 contains an invalid version

Tags: .net, nuget, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

I create a new .net core class library with the following project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postcompile": [
      "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration%"
    ]
  }
}
```

With the "scripts" > "postcompile" I am exporting the nuget package for this library which outputs these files and folder:

```
/netstandard1.5
Solid.Common.Log.1.0.0.nupkg
Solid.Common.Log.1.0.0.symbols.nupkg
```

After this step, I am copying these files into my local nuget folder which I set up before on Visual Studio.

And here is the other project's project.json file (.net core web application) which i want to add the nuget package above.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Solid.Common.Log": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Everything looks fine but it says "Unable to resolve...". Here is the output:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "D:\Projects\Playground\Solid.Disaster\.vs\restore.dg"
log  : Restoring packages for D:\Projects\Playground\Solid.Disaster\src\Solid.Disaster.Web\project.json...
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver/index.json
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethost/index.json
warn : The folder 'D:\Projects\MyNuget\Solid.Common.Log\netstandard1.5' contains an invalid version.
info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/solid.common.log/index.json
info :   NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/solid.common.log/index.json 923ms
error: Unable to resolve 'Solid.Common.Log (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in D:\Projects\Playground\Solid.Disaster\src\Solid.Disaster.Web\project.json...
info : Committing restore...
log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: D:\Projects\Playground\Solid.Disaster\src\Solid.Disaster.Web\project.lock.json
log  : D:\Projects\Playground\Solid.Disaster\src\Solid.Disaster.Web\Solid.Disaster.Web.xproj
log  : Restore failed in 1670ms.
Errors in D:\Projects\Playground\Solid.Disaster\src\Solid.Disaster.Web\Solid.Disaster.Web.xproj
    Unable to resolve 'Solid.Common.Log (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\SolidWrist\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\ProgramData\nuget\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    D:\Projects\MyNuget
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

What might be the problem here? Why can not it resolve this nuget package?

If I add Solid.Common.Log project to web project as an existing project and reference it, everything works fine. But when I try to add it as a nuget package, I am getting this error.

Thanks.

Comment: If I put the package directly into the MyNuget directory, it works fine for me. I don't know what the "invalid version" error means.

Comment: @svick, what is your nuget package manager version? Mine is 3.4.4

Comment: Why don't you use Visual Studio and see how it generates the reference?

Comment: With RC2 you can't generate nuget packages using Visual Studio. You need to use "dotnet pack".

Comment: @BarbarosAlp I don't think that matters. `dotnet restore` uses its own version of the NuGet.CommandLine.XPlat library.

Comment: @svick Do you have any suggestions about how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of moving the files manually using this command handles the issue:

```
nuget.exe add <nupkg> -Source C:\PathToLocalNuget
```

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2955

Answer (score 1):

From the warning in your log file

```
warn : The folder 'D:\Projects\MyNuget\Solid.Common.Log\netstandard1.5' contains an invalid version.
```

It looks like you have copied the whole `Solid.Common.Log` directory in to `D:\Projects\MyNuget` folder.

You need to copy just the `.nupkg` files in to the `MyNuget` folder as described [here](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds#creating-local-feeds).

```
D:\Projects\MyNuget\Solid.Common.Log.1.0.0.nupkg
```

Alternatively, if you would like you can use the new faster alternate layout for NuGet 3.3,  but it requires a bit more work:  http://blog.nuget.org/20150922/Accelerate-Package-Source.html.

Instead of copying the dll across, run the PowerShell cmdlet:

```
Publish-Package "c:\path\to\Solid.Common.Log.1.0.0.nupkg" -PackageSource "D:\Projects\MyNuget"
```

Which will produce a folder structure similar to

```
D:\Projects\MyNuget
    Solid.Common.Log\
        1.0.0\
            Solid.Common.Log.1.0.0.nupkg
            Solid.Common.Log.nuspec
            Solid.Common.Log.1.0.0.nupkg.sha512
```