# How to specify dependency of netcoreapp1.0 on local nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, .net-core

I'm working with latest release of .NET Core 1.0 (`dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121`) under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have a local shared library written under Mono ported to .NET Core (NetStandard 1.6) and I use `dotnet pack` to produce a `.nupkg` and `.symbols.nupkg`.

Now I create a `netcoreapp1.0` using `dotnet new`, how can I write `dependencies` in `project.json` to add the local dll or nuget package to the references, just like adding the `dll` to reference as in VS/Mono previously?

I read [.net core RC2 using own local Nuget Package: The folder netstandard1.5 contains an invalid version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37734618/2906900) but it seems not to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `dotnet` where it can find the NuGet package. You can do that using a NuGet.Config file, either a local one or a global one.

To set up a directory as a package source locally, create a file named NuGet.Config file in the project directory, or one of the directories up the directory tree from it, containing something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="my-local-source" value="path/to/your/local/source" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

To set up a package source globally, change the global NuGet.Config file instead. On Linux, its location is `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost here. After creating own nuget package you should distribute it using your own [Local Nuget Feed](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds). To do this open your `NuGet.config` file and add your local feed inserting new item into packageSources (path to your local folder with nuget packages):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json" />
    ...
    <add key="LocalFeed" value="<path to your local folder>" />
</packageSources>
```

Comment: That page mostly describes how to set up a local package using VS. That won't help much on Linux.

Comment: @svick I expect the same configuration: create new folder, past nuget package to it and modify NuGet.Config adding packagesource, referenced to that folder

Comment: Except the page you linked to does not mention NuGet.Config even once.